# NativeScript core CameraPlus with MLKit doesn't works if saveToGallery is false

Tags: javascript, camera, nativescript

NativeScript core CameraPlus with MLKit doesn't works if saveToGallery is false. Are thera any method to do this without saving the photo in galery? It works with camera basic plugin.

Here is my code:

```
const HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");
const firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args) {
    page = args.object;
    mv = page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();

    page.getViewById("camPlus")
        .addEventListener("photoCapturedEvent", photoCapturedEvent);
};


exports.onCapture = function() {
    camera = page.getViewById("camPlus");
    //Must be false
    camera.takePicture({ saveToGallery: false});
};

function photoCapturedEvent(args) {
    const source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
    source.fromAsset(args.data).then((imageSource) => {
            getTextFromPhoto(imageSource);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
}

function getTextFromPhoto(imageSource) {

    firebase.mlkit.textrecognition.recognizeTextOnDevice({
        image: imageSource
    }).then(function (result) {

        mv.idContainer = getDataFromCameraText(result.text);
        if (mv.idContainer == "") {
            getTextFromPhotoOnline(imageSource);
        } else {
            containerDataIsValid(true);
        }

    }).catch(function (errorMessage) {
        return console.log("ML Kit error: " + errorMessage);
    });
}
```

The method "photoCapturedEvent" gives me an error of undefined:

> JS: Error -> undefined
>
> JS: Asset
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.nativescript.gScanContainer/files/IMG_1543942676583.jpg'
>   cannot be found.

how could I get te image without saving it?

Comment: Is it iOS / Android? The error is still thrown when you comment out the code you have in the `photoCapturedEvent`. Also can you post complete error log?

Comment: Hi, I'm using an Android device. If I comment that there is no errors, the error I see is from console.log("Error -> " + err.message); in the catch of the conversion. The err.message only have  "undefined" s there's no log available. If I change this camera.takePicture({ saveToGallery: false}); for this camera.takePicture({ saveToGallery: true }); it works perfect, but I need to do without savin photos in gallery.

Comment: Oops I write bad the code it must be false not true (I have just updated the description)

Comment: I think it's the `getTextFromPhoto` which might be throwing the error. Try to log the error object and see from which line it was thrown.

Comment: If I comment the "getTextFromPhotoOnline" method Still having the "undefined". I have just updated the question with that method and when log the error I have this "JS: Asset '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.nativescript.gScanContainer/files/IMG_1543942676583.jpg' cannot be found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source code of the plugin and it seems to be a bug. As the error says, they never save the image data in the path they pass on to the photo captured event.

So the only option for you would be, always enable `saveToGallery` and delete the file once you are done with `getTextFromPhoto`.

Comment: Oh a bug, ok so I will do it as you say. Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's an older thread but since this hasn't been fixed in the plugin, for everybody who's running into the same problem, here's a solution:

Instead of always saving the image to the gallery and then tediously fetching it from there, storing it somewhere else and delete the image from the gallery, you can simply add this to the `index.ios.js`:

On line 490 ff you'll find the method `MySwifty.prototype.savePhoto`

On iOS, `this._photoToSave` is a `UIImage` and `ImageAsset` doesn't seem to like that. Hence the asset is empty.

So I added this to the method:

```
if (isIOS) {

  const imageFolder = knownFolders.documents(); 
  const iosImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(this._photoToSave, 0.7);

  const result1 = NSFileManager.defaultManager.createFileAtPathContentsAttributes(imageFolder.path + "/cam_capture.jpg", iosImage, null);

  const asset = new ImageAsset(imageFolder.path + "/cam_capture.jpg");

   _this._owner.get().sendEvent(CameraPlus.photoCapturedEvent, asset);
   _this.resetPreview();

}
```

This saves the image and returns an image asset to the `photoCapturedEvent`.

You can of course change the image name to something more generic and change the image-path, too.

If you want to save the image as PNG instead of JPG, then you'd use

```
const iosImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(this._photoToSave);
```